# accessing file on sdcard android

Tags: android, sd-card, filepath

I am new to Android development. I am trying to use the following code to email a file on my motorola milestone through gmail.

```
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.setType("audio/mp3");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, "file:///sdcard/king1.mp3");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "this is the email content2");
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/king1.mp3"));
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Title:"));
```

Running the code sends the email but the attachment sent is of 0kb. I have seen this problem elsewhere on the internet but I am not sure if I am declaring the correct path to the file. How can I know the exact path of the file? If I mount it, the path I get is /Volumes/NO NAME/king1.mp3.

Or

Do I need to read the file using fileinputstream first?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

to get the root of the sd-card.

Comment: Oh thanks, got it working :) It turns out the root was indeed /sdcard

Comment: However I figured out keeping the sdcard mounted on the computer would not let the phone get access to it.

Comment: The root can be different on different devices.

Answer (score 2):

@sanna is correct that you should use [`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29), however, I would suggest first using [`Environment.getExternalStorageState()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageState%28%29)to determine if you are able to access the storage - for instance, in your example, when the SD card is mounted on the PC.

Answer (score 1):

On my device the external sd data is in a further directory called 'external_sd'.  Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() gives the root directory for the sd card, but if you placed data on your device from a computer, it may be in  "file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/external_sd/"

This was only obvious by using the 'My Files' app on the device, the external_sd directory level is not apparent when mounted on a computer via USB.