# How to show a pic saved in SD on a view?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to show a pic that I'm generated before with the camera and I would like to show that pic in another activity but I don't know how to retrieve the image and show it on the view.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5308997/accessing-file-on-sdcard-android) . This would help you in locating the root of sdcard and also check if its accessible. If you are developing on a device, make sure your sdcard is not mounted on your pc.

Answer (score 1):

Try to save the location that where you will save it, before actually save.

```
String path= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/folderYouWant/";
            File file = new  File(path);
            if (! file.exists()) 
                file.mkdirs();
```

Then, define a name for the image, and concat it on path, like this:

```
String fullAddres=path+imageName+".jpg";
File out = new File(file,imageName+".jpg");
Uri output = Uri.fromFile(out);
```

Then, just use the camera Intent

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT , output);              
            startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

Now you know where you saved your file, and it´s very simple to load the image.

Like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fullAdress); 
            imageWidget.setBackgroundDrawable(null);
            imageWidget.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

If the image is much larger than the widget, take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html):